# How to save ACF data to a unique post and user combination

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

On a Wordpress site I have authors who can submit content and editors who can evaluate and comment on it. Submitted content uses it's own post type and evaluation is done showing a ACF 5 form with text and star rating fields.

My problem is a conceptual one, namely where to save evaluation data to:

1. I can't save it to the post as there have to be evaluations of different editors.
2. I can't save it to the user (neither author nor editor) as authors can submit various contents and editors can evaluate different contents.

So I would need to save the evaluations neither to submitted content (post_1, post_2, ...) nor to evaluators (user_1, user_2, ...) but to a unique post and user combination (evaluation_1_1, evaluation_1_2, ...):

[image]

How is the common way to do so? Do I have to create a new content type "evaluation" with references to submitted content and to evaluating editor and make queries on each evaluation to know if content already has been evaluated?

Or is there an easier way to go? I think of something like a custom *$post_id*:

```
'post_id' => "post_".$post_id."_".$uid,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the help at [ACF forum](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/how-to-save-acf-data-to-a-unique-post-and-user-combination/) I could resolve this issue. The trick is to save evaluation data as array.

I implemented this using a standard ACF form group loaded from the single.php template and adding the following hooks:

1. Hook into **acf/update_value** and retrieve value:

   $value = get_post_meta( $post_id, $field['name']);
2. In the same hook overwrite $value as an array:

   $value[get_current_user_id()] = $value;
3. Hook into **acf/load_field** and retrieve value:

   $value = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), $field['name']);
4. In the same hook extract value from array:

   $field['value'] = $value[0][get_current_user_id()];